# C# - Array.copy target array not long enough

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to copy a byte array into an other (smaller) array,to filter out the last byte of a telegram.

Code:

```
int length = 0;
length = streamLMS.EndRead(x); //write the length of the telegram
byte[] Recvtelegram = new byte[(length-1)];

Array.Copy(LMSRecvBuffer, 0, Recvtelegram, 0, length);
  //Where LMSRecvBuffer is the sourceArray, 0 is the sourceIndex and 
  //destinationIndex and Recvtelegram is the destinationArray.
```

The program works when not subtracting 1 from the length, but I'd like to subtract 1 byte to filter out that last byte.

Error when debugging: 
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Target matrix not long enough.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `aantal` and why is it being used rather than `length-1`?

Comment: And what "aantal" is? It should also be length-1...

Comment: I forgot to translate "aantal", this is Length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
int length = 0;
length = streamLMS.EndRead(x); //write the length of the telegram
byte[] Recvtelegram = new byte[(length-1)];

Array.Copy(LMSRecvBuffer, 0, Recvtelegram, 0, length-1);
```